# PyGI window not destroying

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

Here is my class that is representing preferencies. It loads glade layout from 'preferences.glade'. btn_cancel_clicked_cb and btn_ok_clicked_cb are called when the corresponding buttons are activated. But self.destroy() doesn't do anything. Can somebody explain how to destroy this dialog when after clicking the buttons?

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from common import Prefs

class ViewPrefs(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("preferences.glade")
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        self.rb_input=self.builder.get_object("rb_input")
        self.rb_select=self.builder.get_object("rb_select")

    def run(self, *args):
        window = self.builder.get_object("window_prefs")
        window.show()
        window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        Gtk.main()

    def register_observer(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller

    def btn_cancel_clicked_cb(self,widget):
        self.destroy()

    def btn_ok_clicked_cb(self,widget):
        active = [r for r in self.rb_input.get_group() if r.get_active()][0]
        input_type=active.get_label().lower()
        self.controller.set_prefs(Prefs(input_type=input_type))
        self.destroy()
```

It starts from the main window like that:

```
   prefsview=ViewPrefs()
   prefsview.register_observer(self.controller)
   prefsview.run()
```

Comment: `self` is not `self.window`. In fact, subclassing `Gtk.Dialog` for your case is useless as the dialog part of `self` is never used! If you are requiring a new enough version of GTK+, you can create your dialog as a composite widget template and build your class that way;  otherwise, get rid of the subclass and call `window.destroy()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is not `self.window`. In fact, subclassing Gtk.Dialog for your case is useless as the dialog part of `self` is never used! If you are requiring a new enough version of GTK+, you can create your dialog as a composite widget template and build your class that way (I don't know how to do this with Python; sorry). Otherwise, get rid of the subclass and call `window.destroy()` instead (and, if `window` is really a `Gtk.Dialog`, `window.run()` in your `self.run()`).